# How to return the values of each row where the date is the first date appearing per month (ignores later dates, but not later months)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I have two columns:

Values | Date

The Values column has random whole number values.
The Date column has dates in ascending order as YYYY-MM-DD.

I am hoping to make a new column where only the value from the Values column is returned when the Date column is the earliest occurring date in that month and so on.

| Values | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 412 | 2012-10-11 |
| 545 | 2012-10-12 |
| 876 | 2012-10-17 |
| 142 | 2012-11-02 |
| 315 | 2012-11-05 |

In the above example: I need to return just 412 for 2012-10-11 (ignores other, later October values) and returns 142 for 2012-11-02 (ignores other, later November values), etc.

I am unsure if this is something that should be done in DAX or Power Query. In the end, I need to display the earliest date of each month's value on a line graph on a chart (12-month rolling). Looking at https://dax.guide/nextday/, I imagine using some set of Date/Time functions, or maybe a do-while loop...

Answer (score 0):

One way in powerquery

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Values", Int64.Type}, {"Date", type date}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Date.StartOfMonth([Date]),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"Custom"}, {{"Mindate", each List.Min([Date]), type date}, {"data", each _, type table}}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Values", "Date"}, {"Values", "Date"}),
#"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded data",{{"Date", type date}}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type2", "Result", each if [Mindate]=[Date] then [Values] else null,type number),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Custom", "Mindate"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

or

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Values", Int64.Type}, {"Date", type date}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Date.StartOfMonth([Date]),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom","MinDate",(i)=>List.Min(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each [Custom]=i[Custom])[Date])),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Result", each if [Date] = [MinDate] then [Values] else null),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Custom", "MinDate"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]